# How does the operator precendence of ++ vs -> work when incrementing incrementing a member int through a pointer?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

A question for C++ language lawyers out there. It looks simple but I'm trying to figure out exactly what is going on in my simple program.

```
struct A
{
    int data1;
    int data2;
};

int main()
{
    A myA;
    A* ptr = &myA;
    ptr->data1 = 100;
    ++ptr->data1;                                                                                                                 

    std::cout << "A: " << myA.data1 << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

The above correctly works and outputs 101 on my gcc 4.8.2.

According to things I've read online the ++ and -> operator have the same level of precedence (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k.aspx), thus I would expect precedence to be followed left to right.

If I interpreted left-to-right precedence, then I'd expect ++ptr to execute first rather than ptr->data1. This would lead to markedly different (and incorrect) results.

What am I missing here?

Comment: According to your link (as well as [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), and more importantly the language specification), `->` has higher precedence than `++`, not the same. So that's `++(ptr->data1)`

Comment: In the link you've yourself posted, `->` is listed in group 2, while **prefix** `++` is listed in group 3. What's the problem? Sure, **postfix** `++` is in group 2 as well, but you're not applying that.

Comment: Wow. All this time I had thought prefix and postfix ++ had the same precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence
As u can see, the ++ operator what u used, a prefix operator and this have lower lever precedence than ->.

Suffix operator are same level than ->.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix `++` is of lower priority than `->`. Hence, the expression

```
++ptr->data1;
```

is the same as

```
++(ptr->data1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`->` has a higher order of operation than the *prefix* `++` increment, which you are calling.  So `->` is being called first.

`->` has the same order of precedence as the *postfix* `++` increment, which would amount to the following statement...

`ptr++->data`.  I'm not sure, but I think that doesn't even parse.